# Service oriented architecture - полиморфизм

Tags: ооп, service, полиморфизм

Есть абстрактный базовый класс `Animal` с абстрактным методом `run()`, и 2 наследующих его класса `Tiger` и `Fish`. Оба реализуют метод `run()`, каждый по-своему.

Есть метод сервиса, который в сигнатуре возвращает возвращает `Animal`:

В клиентском коде я вызываю метод `service.getAnimal().run()` и получаю ту или иную реализацию.

Нужно отметить, что классы, производные от `Animal`, хранят и логику, и данные.

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract void run();
}

class Tiger extends Animal {
    private name = "TigerName";
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run from Tiger");
    }
}

class Fish extends Animal {
    private String name = "FishName";

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run from Fish");
    }
}

class ClientService {
    public Animal getAnimal() {
        if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
            return new Tiger();
        } else {
            return new Fish();
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientService service = new ClientService();
        Animal animal = service.getAnimal();
        animal.run(); //полиморфная реализация метода run() из Tiger или Fish
    }
}
```

Если же подходить со стороны SOA - service oriented architecture,  `Animal`, `Tiger` и `Fish` хранят только данные, и у каждого из них есть `AnimalService`, `TigerService` и `FishService` соответственно, которые отвечают за логику.

```
abstract class Animal {

}

class Tiger extends Animal {
    private String name = "nameTiger";
}

class Fish extends Animal {
    private String name = "nameFish";
}

class TigerService {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run from Tiger");
    }
}

class FishService {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run from Fish");
    }
}

class ClientService {
    Animal getAnimal() {
        if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
            return new Tiger();
        } else {
            return new Fish();
        }
    }
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientService service = new ClientService();
        Animal animal = service.getAnimal();
        if (animal.getClass() == Tiger.class) {
            new TigerService().run();
        } else if (animal.getClass() == Fish.class) {
            new FishService().run();
        }
    }
}
```

При таком подходе как мне использовать полиморфизм, чтобы вызвать метод `run()`?

Comment: _При таком подходе как мне использовать полиморфизм_ - так точно так же. В чем принципиальное отличие?

Comment: @Grundy Полиморфизм позволяет мне переопределить логику в дочерних классах. А метод service.getAnimal() отдаст мне объект типа Animal, который теперь не хранит логику. А значит и переопределять нечего. И ссылку на хранящий логику сервис объект типа Animal тоже не хранит. Тогда как мне добраться до метода run()?

Comment: а где ты хочешь расположить этот метод?

Comment: @Grundy в сервисе, скорее всего, раз в entity-классе нельзя. В TigerService  и FishService

Comment: добавь желаемый пример вызова. Пока не совсем понятно как у тебя в этом примере все 6 классов связаны

Comment: @Grundy добавил пример

Comment: Не, пример с классами понятно, я имел ввиду пример где у тебя три сервиса задействованы

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: Делайте у них метод getService, который бы вернул их родной сервис. Если хотите совсем без методов, то это будет уже не полиморфизм.

Comment: странно почему тег [java] не приняли в правке, разве код не на ней?

Comment: @trollingchar getService нельзя. Entity не должен знать о сервисе. Тем более что сервисов работающих с этим Entity может быть несколько

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How to deal with Java Polymorphism in Service Oriented Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7527481/2881286)